# Update Apache POI 4 to 5

Tags: 20.04, java

I'm using 20.04, in there the Apache POI is still the very old version 4.0.1.

Could you consider to upgrade the POI to newer version i.e. 5.0? Because it is having a signature problem with other packages as shown below.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed:   
new org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook((o:InputStream)  
[o:FileInputStream]). Cause: java.lang.SecurityException: class  
 "org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package VM:  
11.0.10@https://ubuntu.com/" at:\n#-19  
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1151)\n#-18  
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:906)\n#-17  
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1015)\n#-16 java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174 
)\n#-15  
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2419)\n#-14  
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)\n#-13  
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)\n#-12  
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClas in /var/www/erp/library/javabridge-7.2.1/java/Java.inc on line 223
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: See also https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libapache-poi-java for why 5.0 has not even been packaged yet for Debian (Hint: They could use more help from community members like you)